# In Pathfinder: Kingmaker, is there a way to tell if a container or door is locked before trying to open it?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

It appears to me that the cursor icon when hovering a normal container is the same as a locked container. I would like to know in advance when I am trying to unlock a container in order to use Guidance on myself, first.

Is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not particularly clean.

What I do is position my entire party a fair distance away from the container and ask them all to open it. If the game sends my character with the highest Trickery forward then I know the object is locked and I can stop the operation and prep accordingly. If a random, non-trickster character walks forward then I know the object isn't locked.